# How to keep your method at particular position for a required time?

Tags: android

I am developing a card based game, in the game user can swap it's own card with other deck cards. It is a turn based game, following is the method which determine which player turn is now and perform the further operations.

```
  private void startGame() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Inside Start Game method");
    if(current_player>=no_of_players)
        current_player=0;
    else
        current_player++;
   if(current_player==0) {
       parent.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(parent,"Your turn", 0).show();
               // Stay Here till the User does not swap the cards by touching
   }
  else if(current_player==2)
    {
       pickBestCard(Top_Center_Player, DiscardedDeck.getCard());

    }


}
```

The Human Player can swap the card by touching them. However the above method does not giving me time to swap the cards. It is immediately went to next player. I have tried to create a timer inside the `if(current_player==0)` condition so that Human Player will get enough time to make the swap. However i don't find it as an appropriate solution. Because, what if Human Player does not able to make a decision in the allocated time.So i want to stay inside `if(current_player==0)` condition till the Main Player does not make it's move.
If any able to provide any solution or suggestion it will be very grateful. I am not able to find any solution.

Edit: Added more code

**Main Activity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   try {

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      MySurfaceView surfaceView;
      surfaceView = (MySurfaceView) findViewById((R.id.surfaceView));
      surfaceView.setActivity(this);


   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```

}

**Thread Class**

```
public class MySurfaceViewThread extends Thread {
private MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder mySurfaceHolder;
boolean running;

/**
 * Time per frame for 60 FPS
 */
private static final int MAX_FRAME_TIME = (int) (1000.0 / 60.0);

public MySurfaceViewThread(SurfaceHolder paramSurfaceHolder, MySurfaceView paramSurfaceView)
{
    mySurfaceHolder=paramSurfaceHolder;
    mySurfaceView=paramSurfaceView;
}

public void setRunning(boolean run){
    running=run;

}

public SurfaceHolder getMySurfaceHolder()
{
    return mySurfaceHolder;
}
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    long frameStarttime= 0;
    long frameTime;
    while(running)
    {
        if(mySurfaceHolder==null)
        {
            return;   // To fix Surface not found error;
        }
        c=null;
        try{
            frameStarttime=System.nanoTime();
            c= mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            synchronized (mySurfaceHolder) {
               mySurfaceView.render(c);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           // Log.e("Thread Class run method","exception",e);
        }

        finally {
            if (c!=null)
            {
                mySurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

        // calculate the time required to draw the frame in ms
        frameTime = (System.nanoTime() - frameStarttime) / 1000000;

        if (frameTime < MAX_FRAME_TIME){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(MAX_FRAME_TIME - frameTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }

    }

}
}
```

**Surface View Class**

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (thread.getMySurfaceHolder()) {
     //   Log.d(TAG, "Inside Touch Event");
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return true;
}

  public void render(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT,PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    drawDealtDeck(canvas);
    setDiscardedDeck();
    drawDiscardedDeck(canvas);
    setMainPlayer();
    DrawMainPlayerDeck(canvas);
    SetTopCenterPlayerDeck();
    DrawTopCenterPlayerDeck(canvas);
    startGame();

}
 private void startGame() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Inside Start Game method");
    if(current_player>=no_of_players)
        current_player=0;
    else
        current_player++;
   if(current_player==0) {
       parent.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(parent,"Your turn", 0).show();
               new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {
                   @Override
                   public void onTick(long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(parent,"seconds remaining" +l/1000,0);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onFinish() {

                   }
               }.start();
           }
       });
   }
  else if(current_player==2)
    {
       pickBestCard(Top_Center_Player, DiscardedDeck.getCard());

    }


}
}
```

Comment: you can add a "touchListener" to the card and enable and disable accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { /*Your code*/ });
```

creates a new Runnable (a piece of code that can be run) and then tells the UI-Thread
to run this piece of code when it has time to do so. After this is done the current thread continues with the next line of code, in this case, it returns from the method.

If the thread that is executing the `startGame()` method is the UI-Thread, then your call to `runOnUiThread()` is not needed (all it does is postpone the execution by an unknown amount of time). If you have another thread that is running the `startGame()` method then you probably need to implement some kind of synchronization between this thread and the UI-Thread.

It's hard to say more without any information about when `startGame()` is being called. What you probably need to do is to call `startGame()` whenever the user has completed his turn.

EDIT:

**Running the next turn logic**

In your current implementation, the `startGame()` method is being called as part of your rendering routine. This means it gets called around 60 times per second. This is not what you want.

The code in the `startGame()` method looks to me like the method should really be called `nextTurn()`. Since you have a turn-based game, what you need to do is call the `nextTurn()` method whenever the player has completed his turn. Like Ridcully mentioned in his answer, an 'EndTurn' button is probably what you need. In addition to that, each turn could also be time-limited.

In my personal opinion, it would be a good style to keep the rendering and game logic on different threads. From what I can currently see, your game logic is not very heavy, so it won't be a problem to run it on the UI-Thread.

In Android, all onTouch and onClick callbacks are run on the UI-Thread. This means that you can simply register an onClickListener for a new 'EndTurn' button, and call your `nextTurn()` method from the onClick. If you wanted to implement an additional timeout it could look something like this.

```
// You can run code on the UI-Thread using this Handler
private Handler myMainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper);

// This is the code to run when the timeout is reached
private Runnable myTimeoutRunnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      nextTurn();
   }
};

// This is the code to run when the 'EndTurn' button is clicked
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   // Remove any pending timeouts.
   myMainThreadHandler.removeCallbacks(myTimeoutRunnable);
   // Run your next turn game logic       
   nextTurn();
   // And then add a new timeout in 30.000 ms
   myMainThreadHandler.postDelayed(myTimeoutRunnable, 30*1000);
}
```

Note that you still need to make an initial call to `myMainThreadHandler.postDelayed(myTimeoutRunnable, 30*1000);` before the very first turn of the game or the first turn will have unlimited time.

**Using the Android Choreographer**

As a side note, in your MySurfaceViewThread class, you have a `Thread.sleep(100)` call that will pause your rendering thread for 100 ms.
If you do this you cannot achieve 60 fps, the best you can do is 10.

You also try to manually calculate when you need to render the next frame to achieve 60 fps. It is difficult and unnecessary to do it this way. You can use the Choreographer class provided by the framework instead. The boilerplate code for what you want to do would look something like this.

```
public class Renderer extends Thread implements Choreographer.FrameCallback {
   private Choreographer myChoreographer = null;
   private Looper myLooper = null;

   public Renderer() {
      start();
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      Log.i(TAG, "Renderer started correctly");

      Looper.prepare();

      myChoreographer = Choreographer.getInstance();
      myChoreographer.postFrameCallbackDelayed(this, 0);

      myLooper = Looper.myLooper();

      Looper.loop();

      myChoreographer = null;

      Log.i(TAG, "Renderer finished correctly");
   }

   @Override
   public void doFrame(final long frameTimeNanos) {
      myChoreographer.postFrameCallbackDelayed(this, 0);

      Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
      try {
         // Do all the drawing on the canvas here
      }
      finally {
         getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
      }
   }

   public void stopRender() {
      myLooper.quit();
   }
}
```

Note that the code above assumes that the Renderer is an inner class of the SurfaceView. You can read more about SurfaceView and how it works as well as the Choreographer [here](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture).

Hope this helped :)

Comment: I have added more detailed code, let me know if it help's.

Answer (score 0):

You said, this is a round based game. So, you'll need some way (e.g. button) to allow the current player to say he's done with his turn (i.e. has changed all cards he wanted to).

Only in that event (e.g. button pressed) you should increase the `current_user` counter.